# Replace last item's value of a dict by the first item's value of the pair

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```py
my_dict = {
    'first' : {'key1' : 'first_value1', 'key2': 'first_value2', 'key3' : 'not available'},
    'second' : {np.nan : 'second_value1', 'key2': 'not available', 'key3' : 'not available'},
    'third' : {np.nan : 'third_value1', 'key2': 'not available', 'key3' : 'not available'},
    'fourth' : {np.nan : 'fourth_value1', 'key2': 'fourth_value2', 'key3' : 'fourth_value3'}
}
```

I want to transform this dict to look as follows:

```py
my_dict = {
    'first' : {'key1' : 'first_value1', 'key2': 'first_value2', 'key3' : 'second_value1'},
    'second' : {'key2': 'not available', 'key3' : 'third_value1'},
    'third' : {'key2': 'not available', 'key3' : 'fourth_value1'},
    'fourth' : {'key2': 'fourth_value2', 'key3' : 'fourth_value3'}
}
```

Note that I am also removing the `np.nan` keys that are in the beginning and not removing or replacing the `not available` values that are in the middle of each dictionary.

I tried:

```
updated_dict = {}

keys = list(my_dict.keys())
num_keys = len(keys)

for i in range(num_keys):
    current_key = keys[i]
    next_key = keys[i + 1] if i + 1 < num_keys else None
    
    updated_dict[current_key] = {}
    for subkey, subvalue in my_dict[current_key].items():
        if subkey != np.nan:
            if subvalue == 'not available' and next_key is not None:
                updated_dict[current_key][subkey] = my_dict[next_key][np.nan]
            else:
                updated_dict[current_key][subkey] = subvalue

my_dict = updated_dict
```

However, I am not able to take care of the middle items that are `not available`, they need to be intact.